# Keyboard layout English UK international "with" AltGr for typing Ñ does not exist in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Under Gnome, I usually work the keyboard layout "English US alt.Intl." using Alt Gr + N to write the Ñ but I can't do the same on my work laptop that have an English UK keyboard.

Looks like there isn't an international layout that allow me to use the same keystroke with an UK keyboard. Does someone know how can I resolve?

EDIT TLTR: I'm looking for is the UK Intl. with Alt Gr which is used to activating the extra symbols, as you can see from this link http://zolid.com/uk-intl-kb/index.htm

Comment: Switch to the _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ keyboard layout?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson English (US, intl., with dead keys) does have the Ñ but it mess up other symbols. What I'm looking for is the UK Intl. with Alt Gr which is used to activating the extra symbols, as you can see from this link http://zolid.com/uk-intl-kb/index.htm

Comment: As far as I can see there is no layout named "UK Intl. with Alt Gr". Please be precise about which XKB keyboard layout you want to use.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson that's the problem. On Windows, the English UK International layout can do the Ñ (Alt Gr + N), and all the other UK symbol where are mean to be with this layout. If I use the US Intl layout I can write the Ñ but all the other symbols are scrambled up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` for editing and modify the <kbd>N</kbd> key. Example:

```
--- gb.orig 2021-07-05 10:17:07.431348509 +0200
+++ gb  2021-07-05 10:23:46.833021094 +0200
@@ -21,6 +21,8 @@
 
     key <BKSL> { [numbersign, asciitilde,   dead_grave,   dead_breve ] };
     key <LSGT> { [ backslash,        bar,          bar,    brokenbar ] };
+    
+    key <AB06> { [         n,          N,       ntilde,       Ntilde ] };
 
     include "level3(ralt_switch_multikey)"
 };
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

"English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)" in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Settings > keyboard > + > English (United States) > "English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)"

"AltGr + n" write "ñ"